# Pig count occurrence of strings in text messages

Tags: csv, hadoop, count, apache-pig

I've got two files - venues.csv and tweets.csv. I want to count for each of the venues the number of times occurs in the tweet message from the tweets file.

I've imported the csv files in HCatalog.

**What I managed to do so far:**

I know how to filter the `text` fields and to get these tuples that contain `'Shell'` their tweet messages. I want to do the same but not with hard-coded `Shell`, rather for each `name` from the `venuesNames` bag. How can I do that? Also then how can I use the `generate` command properly to generate a new bag that is matching the results from the count with the names of the venues?

```
a = LOAD 'venues_test_1' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = LOAD 'tweets_test_1' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

venuesNames = foreach a generate name;

countX = FILTER b BY (text matches '.*Shell.*');

venueToCount = generate ('Shell' as venue, COUNT(countX) as countVenues); 

DUMP venueToCount;
```

**The files that I'm using are:**

**tweets.csv**

```
created_at,text,location
Sat Nov 03 13:31:07 +0000 2012, Sugar rush dfsudfhsu, Glasgow
Sat Nov 03 13:31:07 +0000 2012, Sugar rush ;dfsosjfd HAHAHHAHA, London
Sat Apr 25 04:08:47 +0000 2009, at Sugar rush dfjiushfudshf, Glasgow
Thu Feb 07 21:32:21 +0000 2013, Shell gggg, Glasgow
Tue Oct 30 17:34:41 +0000 2012, Shell dsiodshfdsf, Edinburgh
Sun Mar 03 14:37:14 +0000 2013, Shell wowowoo, Glasgow
Mon Jun 18 07:57:23 +0000 2012, Shell dsfdsfds, Glasgow
Tue Jun 25 16:52:33 +0000 2013, Shell dsfdsfdsfdsf, Glasgow
```

**venues.csv**

```
city,name
Glasgow, Sugar rush
Glasgow, ABC
Glasgow, University of Glasgow
Edinburgh, Shell
London, Big Ben
```

I know that these are basic questions but I'm just getting started with Pig and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I see in your example that you have a tweet like "Shell...Glasgow" though in your venus file you indicate Shell is in Edinburgh.  Do you want to require that the city match?  Or any tweet with the venue name counts, regardless of where it was sent?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus Well at first I'm looking in the simplest most case, so I'll be happy just to count the for each venue - how many time occurs in the tweet messages. So for example `Shell` occurs in 5 twitter messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that your list of venue names is unique.  If not, then you have more problems anyway because you will need to disambiguate which venue is being talked about (perhaps by reference to the city fields).  But disregarding that potential complication, here is what you can do:

You have described a fuzzy join.  In Pig, if there is no way to coerce your records to contain standard values (and in this case, there isn't without resorting to a UDF), you need to use the `CROSS` operator.  Use this with caution because if you cross two relations with `M` and `N` records, the result will be a relation with `M*N` records, which might be more than your system can handle.

The general strategy is 1) `CROSS` the two relations, 2) Create a custom regex for each record*, and 3) Filter those that pass the regex.

```
venues = LOAD 'venues_test_1' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
tweets = LOAD 'tweets_test_1' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

/* Create the Cartesian product of venues and tweets */
crossed = CROSS venues, tweets;
/* For each record, create a regex like '.*name.*'
regexes = FOREACH crossed GENERATE *, CONCAT('.*', CONCAT(venues::name, '.*')) AS regex;
/* Keep tweet-venue pairs where the tweet contains the venue name /*
venueMentions = FILTER regexes BY text MATCHES regex;

venueCounts = FOREACH (GROUP venueMentions BY venues::name) GENERATE group, COUNT($1);
```

The sum of all `venueCounts` might be more than the number of tweets, if some tweets mention multiple venues.

*Note that you have to be a little careful with this technique, because if the venue name contains characters that have special interpretations in Java regular expressions, you'll need to escape them.

Comment: Thanks you! Your solution is working, but it will work only for small input. Do you think there is another way without creating the cartesian product of these two relations?